# count unique values in vector in clojure

Tags: clojure

I was wondering if anyone can help me understand how can i do the below code in clojure :

```
int[] secondArray = new int[500];

for (int i = 0; i < firstArray.length; i++) 
{
  secondArray[firstArray[i]] += 1;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You could probably use the [`frequencies`](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/frequencies) function:

```
user=> (frequencies [:foo :bar :baz :foo :foo])
{:foo 3, :bar 1, :baz 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's walk through a fairly direct translation where we treat the input vector as a sequence and then reduce it into the desired result:

First define some immutable vectors containing our starting states:

```
boo> (def firstVector (vec (take 30 (repeatedly #(rand-int 10)))))
#'boo/firstVector
boo> firstVector 
[9 0 4 5 0 7 3 9 0 0 6 6 5 5 9 4 0 1 3 6 4 9 5 8 8 3 4 6 7 6]
boo> (def secondVector (vec (take 10 (repeat 0))))
#'boo/secondVector
boo> secondVector
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

We then want an expression that `inc`s the appropriate element in the second array

```
boo> (assoc secondVector 4 (inc (secondVector 4)))
[0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0]
```

Then we want the result of that to be passed to the frist element in firstVector, followed by the result of that being passed to the second element in firstVector and so forth. The `reduce` function does this:

```
boo> (reduce #(assoc %1 %2 (inc (%1 %2))) secondVector firstVector)
[5 1 0 3 4 4 5 2 2 4]
```

in the reducer function %1 (the first argument) is the current accumulated result, and %2(the second argument) is the current value from the input sequence (firstVector).